# Appengine Maven Project run as wtp on local server issue

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, appengine-maven-plugin

i have been trying to run a maven project as dynamic web project in local server to get hot re-deployment feature, which is currently not available appengine maven plugin with eclipse

i referred : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform

this project works fine when running using mvn:appengine devserver command, but we i tried to run on local server, i get the following error

**Error occurred during initialization of VM**

**agent library failed to init: instrument**

**Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /Volumes/My**

any idea what this error means?

Note: **the ultimate goal was to some how synchronous changes in src war folder to be present in target directory to avoid stopping and starting server for every changes**

any solutions to solve this issue is most welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Any Suggestion on this question ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the ultimate goal, `mvn appengine:devserver` already supports reloading:

> When the server is running, it continuously checks to determine
>   whether appengine-web.xml has changed. If it has, the server does a
>   hot reload of the application. This means that you do not need to stop
>   and restart your application because of changes to appengine-web.xml

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven#managing_and_running_a_project_with_the_app_engine_maven_plugin

Comment: its just reloads appengine-web.xml file only, it will not reload css/js/html which is of prime importance, even we can make java classes recomplied by settings outputpath in build section

Comment: If you do mvn appengine:package while running mvn appengine:devserver it reloads the whole thing, not just appengine-web.xml. Have you ever tried it?

Comment: you meant run mvn appengine:devserver every time i update any file, i do not that, i want some kind of automation which will reload files

Comment: alex, i can run mvn:appengine devsever which builds the package and run on devserver, but while app is running if u makes changes to any css/js/html files it will not reload

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/) installed? It handles web assets being updated in a running container (including the devserver through [GPE](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/)).

Comment: ya i have installed wtp but no use, can u give me some step to configure it (in terms of this hot reloading)

Comment: wtp is throwing errors as below 

also, i get another error 

**Description Resource Path Location Type
The App Engine SDK '/Users/Ramesh/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.3/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.3.jar' on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location '/Users/Ramesh/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk/1.9.3/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.3.jar' is not a directory) RameshProfile  Unknown Google App Engine Problem**

Comment: Also this error,

**java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.properties.ui.GaeProjectPropertyPage.saveChangesToAppEngineWebXml(GaeProjectPropertyPage.java:890)**

its from plugin com.google.gdt.eclipse.core

Comment: its have been spending many hours trying to fix this! ever solution i try endup in some form of errors, this doesn't have to be so painful

Comment: Try Project -> Properties - > Google -> Appengine and click 'Configure SDKS' - those in an error state will have a red cross next to them.